# What is going wrong with web deployment from Visual Studio and App service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Suddenly Web Deployment started failing.

```
Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Offline.htm'.
```

I stopped the service, but deployment still fails.

When I tried to delete any file from wwwroot in Kudu PowerShell UI I get error "404 file not find", but that file is still displayed after refresh.
When I tried to delete file directly in powershell I get error

```
Cannot remove item D:\home\site\wwwroot\Azure.Storage.dll: Invalid access to memory location.
At line:1 char:1
+ del .\Azure.Storage.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\home\site\wwwroot\Azure.Storage. 
   dll:FileInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

I deleted the service, recreated it and the first deployment from Visual Studio was Ok. But next day deployment failed again. The only thing between that deployments was deployment from VSTS. But I was able to deploy from VSTS and from Visual Studio in any order before without any problem.

I'm the Owner of that App Service.

Deployment log.

```
(2018-08-06 13:05:03) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Could not find file 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Offline.htm'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings.CreateWriter(String outputFileName)
   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(String outputFileName, XmlWriterSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddAppOfflineFilesToEachApp(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean whatIf)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AppOfflineRuleHandler.AddChild(DeploymentSyncContext syncContext, DeploymentObject destinationParentObject, DeploymentObject& sourceObject, Boolean& proceed)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.HandleAddChild(DeploymentObject destParent, DeploymentObject sourceObject, Int32 position)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncDirPathChildren(DeploymentObject destRoot, DeploymentObject sourceRoot)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenNoOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildrenOrder(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.SyncChildren(DeploymentObject dest, DeploymentObject source)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncContext.ProcessSync(DeploymentObject destinationObject, DeploymentObject sourceObject)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObject.SyncToInternal(DeploymentObject destObject, DeploymentSyncOptions syncOptions, PayloadTable payloadTable, ContentRootTable contentRootTable, Nullable`1 syncPassId, String syncSessionId)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleSync(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData, Nullable`1 passId, String user, String siteName)
Publish failed to deploy.
```

Comment: Please consider marking an answer below if this solved your issue. Just saved me :-)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

All of a sudden VSTS default deployment mode became Run-From-Zip.

The solution is setting *Select deployment method* checkbox in VSTS deploy and be sure *Web Deploy* is selected.

To "unlock" the service you need to delete setting *WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE* from *Application settings* page in the Azure Portal - it is under 'Configuration'

[image]

Comment: This has been killing me, thank you so much for posting the answer!!

Comment: It does not work for me. I have not `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP` in appsetting.json

Comment: It's not in appsettings, it's in Azure App settings.

Comment: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is the new name

Comment: To add ensure you check your Deployment Slots as the setting may exist in all slots.

Comment: This saved me aswell, Can this be marked as answer?

Comment: Instead of deleting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`, it can be set to `0`.

Comment: Web Deploy check box is checked for me and I cannot find this setting anywhere.

Comment: We deleted and this fixed our problem

Comment: sonofaB! that was it for me

Comment: I am not able to find this in Azure App Settings.  I can see this key over there "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM"

Comment: I was trying a web deploy method of publish profile on a linux hosted service.. I was able to get it resolved by deploying using FTP Deploy method

Comment: @Rambalac, I don't know where to check this in Azure DevOps, could you please provide me the steps to do this? Right now I am searching this setting in Azure DevOps's Pipeline tab settings and not there.

Comment: Happened to me recently. MS seem to have updated all my functions to WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP.... WHY!?!??!!?

Answer (score 49):

I hade the same problem today with net core 2.2 and the solution was to remove setting "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" in azure appsettings

Comment: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is added every time you deploy with an Azure DevOps pipeline.  You will need to remove it before publishing via VS 2019.  To delete, scroll to the far right and click the trash can icon.

Answer (score 24):

We got hit by this same issue - the file system becomes readonly when `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1`. **Azure App Service** seems to be adding this app setting automatically during recent platform upgrades.

I do suggest using Run-From-Package over web deploy - but you can easily revert their forced updates by setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=0`. If you are on Azure DevOps - the [latest version of App Service Deploy v4 supports Run-From-Package](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19672#issuecomment-479975653).

Answer (score 12):

The reason for this is because the [AzureWebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task in Azure DevOps (VSTS) Pipeline, updates the 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE' to '1'. This is primarily used by Azure Functions, where we need to deploy the entire package (and there by making the wwwroot as read-only). While its very useful in Functions, you will see weird things in normal Web App (such as App_Offline not found, the wwwroot/lib folder not found, you will see older files in the FTP folder but latest ones in the Kudu console etc).

The simplest fix is to update the setting 'deploymentMethod' to 'zipDeploy' in your YAML file.

Answer (score 12):

Go to Configurations -> Application settings in your azure portal change the value of  '**WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE**' from '1' to '0'. And then publish again.

This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the appp settings WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP then retry deploy from VS. This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you choose the deployment method by yourself in the release step this should not appear:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide details? Where are you updating this?

Comment: It is in the azure devops release pipeline a deployment step.

Answer (score 1):

For those who cannot find setting in azure portal, please refer below steps.

1. Login to portal
2. Goto your app
3. search configuration

[image]

Name 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE' will be there is list.

Answer (score 0):

My deployment was failing with the same message and stack trace, but was caused by a policy assignment that disallowed the location for my resource.

(The resource had been created in US West, and then a policy was applied at the tenant root level that only allowed US West 2.)

After the policy was updated, the deployment succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when VS has issues finding your swagger xml file.
Right-click your project > Properties > Build will take you to the correct page.

Check the "XML Documentation File:" box. This resolved the issue for me but you may need to ensure that the release or debug folder are included in the path. i.e. bin\Release\ProjectName.xml or similar

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar error but for me it was:

```
Access to the path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Offline.htm' is denied
```

Got this when trying to publish a `.NET 5` application. Fixed by setting correct `.NET` version in General settings for my App Service:

[image]

Comment: If you vote down please add a comment why. Very hard to improve answers otherwise